# Allocating arrays in C++

Tags: c++

When I started programming with C++ I was learned to allocate the array size by using dynamic memory allocation as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int nArrayLength;

    cout << "Enter an array length: ";
    cin  >> nArrayLength;

    int *nArray = new int[nArrayLength];

    // contents

    delete[] nArray;

    return 0;
}
```

Now I tried the following code using Code::Blocks 12.11 with the mingw32-g++ // GNU GCC compiler.

```
int main()
{
    int nArrayLength;

    cout << "Enter an array length: ";
    cin  >> nArrayLength;

    int nArray[nArrayLength];

    return 0;
}
```

This also works fine.

Therefore, why should I use dynamic memory allocation in this case when the easier method also works fine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use neither.

The first is valid, but it's C-style code. The second is non-standard code - it's accepted by that compiler because of some extension.

Use a `std::vector` instead:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    int nArrayLength;

    cout << "Enter an array length: ";
    cin  >> nArrayLength;

    std::vector<int> nArray(nArrayLength);

    return 0;
}
```

A `vector` has the same semantics as an array, it can grow dynamically (and automatically), and does all the pesky memory management under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

The second code is not valid standard C++. It uses a compiler extension called variable length arrays. See [the GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

However, there is a [proposal for variable length arrays with automatic storage duration](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3639.html) that has been adopted for C++14.

Answer (score 1):

Compile the second code with `-pedantic` option if you're using GCC. It would not compile.

It is because it is not Standard conformant. Variable Length Array (VLA) is not in the Standard C++. It is a compiler extension.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you don't know the size of your array beforehand, so you need to allocate storage for it that may grow or shrink dynamically. You should use `std::vector` because it manages the array storage transparently.

If you are forced to use C-style arrays, use them like in the first code snippet, the second one is not standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you want to use the stack or the heap.

You can also use auto_ptr if you want your heap allocation to be released automatically when scope goes out.